# Как изменить физику сворачивания/раскрытия AppBarLayout?

Tags: android

Можно ли изменить физику сворачивания/раскрытия `AppBarLayout`? Меня не устраивает стандартная - в частности, прямая зависимость длительности сворачивания от скорости проведения пальцем, из-за этого иногда не получается коротким движением пальца свернуть `AppBar`. Т.е. я хочу установить фиксированную длительность раскрытия/закрытия `AppBar` (после того, как пользователь поднял палец), но стандартных средств для реализации этого нет. Полностью переписывать как-то тоже не хочется..

Comment: Возможно, бред, но попробуйте поставить `onTouchListener` на корневую `view` и в `onTouch` вызывать `onTouch` у `AppBarLayout`и передавать удвоенный y (игрек)

Comment: @Flippy, не особо поможет, да и дергаться будет слишком резко, на мой взгляд. Попытаюсь переопределить некоторые функции из `Behavior` (подкласса `AppBarLayout`), посмотрим, что получится